# Representing a distribution of probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, mean, population

I'm running a simulation where, for every iteration $i$, I get a detection probabilities $P_i$.  Because of the law of total expectation, I think the *overall* detection probability (i.e. marginalizing over all iterations) is just the average, $\langle P_i \rangle = 1/N \sum P_i$.  **But how do I calculate error-bars (lets say, the 1-sigma confidence region) for detection probability?**

The distribution of $P_i$ is highly non-gaussian, and non-symmetric around the mean: such that the the values of P for the 16th and 84th percentiles of $P_i$ are *both* below the average.  So naively it seems like my "error bars" should be plotted in a completely different place than my average / overall detection probability.   If this were a probability distribution, I would want to plot the median or mode, and then (something like) the 1-sigma region around it... but the median or mode of a distribution of probabilities doesn't sound quite right as meaningful to me.

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by an "error bar."  After all, you aren't describing the collection of data, you're describing a simulation: and in such a simulation, you *know* all the parameters.

Comment: I have removed your more objectionable comment because it has nothing to do with your question and seems intended solely to offend. I have asked only for clarification of your question so that it will have the greatest possible chance of being understood and correctly answered. If you really want an answer, please curb your attacks on the messenger and focus instead on how you might improve the statement of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think @whuber raised good points in the comments (and you were quite rude to him) but if what you want is to estimate standard errors of probabilities (and ignoring the fact that there are no errors, since it's a simulation) then the usual formula is

$$ SE = \frac{\sqrt{pq}}{n}$$

where $q = 1 -p$ which is probably OK if p is not too near 0 or 1 and N is not too small (in a simulation, a small N would be easy to fix).

If p is close to 0 or 1, then there are alternative methods.  Many of these methods are available in statistical packages - certainly they are in R and SAS and I'm guessing they are in all the other "biggies".